# How to alter the already created table?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I used following command to create a table.

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now for some reason, I have to make some changes to the entity.

After making some changes to the entity class when I try to run this command again. I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class App\Entity\BlogPost, because the name is already in use in
```

I delete the already created table from the db manually and try to run but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hello, when you update you database schema it's advise to use `migrations` like [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-adding-more-fields).

Comment: Check the filenames and namespaces. This kind of error can crop up when there is a typo or mismatch in classnames.

Comment: Moreover, the error is not linked to the database but to the `Entity` in PHP. Maybe you have the class used two times, the autoload has some bug, there is cache, etc

Comment: Make sure than you entity class is excluded from services folder... It looks like this file is already instantiated somewhere